# plot a (r,phi) vector in 3D

Tags: plotting, vector

I have a vector, with its 3 components function just of the position in the x,y plane (as r, phi):

```
n[r_, f_] := {Cos[f + g] Sin[th[r]], 
   m Sin[f + g] Sin[th[r]], 
   Cos[th[r]]};
```

with

```
th[r_] := \[Pi]/2 - \[Pi] E^(-r^2);
```

(m,g are constants).

How can I plot it as a vector field in 3D, and as a density field on the xy plane?

Comment: Have you tried converting to Cartesian coordinates already?

Comment: not sure how to do it in M

Comment: How about `VectorPlot3D[
 n[r, f] /. {r -> Sqrt[x1^2 + x2^2], f -> ArcTan[x1, x2]}, {x1, -1, 
  1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, -1, 1}]` (of course with values for `m` and `g`)? By the density, I dont know what you mean, but may be `VectorDensityPlot` helps you.

Comment: sorry, was it just simple as that? I was lost into CoordinateTransform, TransformedField ... and didnt think of such a simple way (ashamed)

Comment: no worries, we all have those moments taking a hard look at something and with some help realizing that "wait ... one banana ... plus one banana ...... are two bananas !!!!" :D